Excel Formula To Get Last Non Zero or Not Blank Value in a row And Return Value
Ive seen a few similar questions on here but it didnt work for me.
Im trying to find the last non blank cell and cell without certain text criteria in a row; which the data range is not contiguous with blank cells in between.
Ive tried to look up for solutions with index, match, max, if, lookup with <>""; but still couldnt figure out the right formula, felt like im so close to it but i cant find the last pieces of puzzle.

I wanted to exclude all ICU_Approval wording here with the last non-blank cell, which is meant to be SI-003, and return with 7,16,or 25
My attempt of formula:
=INDEX(S9:AA9,MAX(IF((S1:AA1<>"ICU_Approval")*(S1:AA1<>""),ROW(S1:AA1))))
It returns with number 1, which is not the last cell from row
=LOOKUP(2,1/($S$1:$AA$1<>$U$1),$S10:$AA10)
It returns with number 18, which didnt exclude the blank cell
=+MAX(IF((S1:AA1<>"ICU_Approval")*(S1:AA1<>""),ROW(S1:AA1)))
It returns with number 1, which is not the last cell from row

Try using the following formula :


=LOOKUP(2,1/((S$1:AA$1<>"ICU_Approval")*(S$1:AA$1<>"")),S9:AA9)


Or using INDEX()+MATCH()
=INDEX(S9:AA9,MATCH(2,1/((S$1:AA$1<>"ICU_Approval")*(S$1:AA$1<>""))))


Or, can use AGGREGATE() function as well:
=AGGREGATE(14, 7, S9:AA9/(1/((S$1:AA$1<>"ICU_Approval")*(S$1:AA$1<>""))),1)


Or, Using TAKE() & TOCOL()
=TAKE(TOCOL(S9:AA9/(1/((S$1:AA$1<>"ICU_Approval")*(S$1:AA$1<>""))),2),-1)



omg, i was so close!  thanks for the advise;  glad to learn the take and tocol function also, but i think i have the older version of excel, function database needed to be updated. apprecaited xx

@user1987243 I tried to add as much I can, so it helps in learning!! Glad to know you have resolved it. Thanks!!
